Using boundary conditions to find periodicity in integrable toda-chain
I've been thinking about the one-dimensional Toda chain which is an integrable system, as a toy-model for a crystal. I'm trying to find methods to find the natural periodicity which should be occurring in the crystal to be in its crystallized form, which would have the lowest energy. I know that there has been research done on symmetry breaking by imposing boundary conditions, as in the work by Sklyanin in 1988 'Boundary conditions for integrable quantum systems.' I was wondering, if I'm able to impose boundary conditions at specific positions in my chain, when it would match with the natural periodicity it wouldn't change the energy, and thus it would still be in its lowest state. Therefore I could find the periodicity by adding boundary conditions and seeing how this would affect the solution of the Hamiltonian. What do you think of this approach?

I don't quite follow. What do you mean by 'impose boundary conditions at specific positions in my chain' -- that instead of the periodic chain you try to insert a twist at a specific position, or to replace the periodic boundaries by 'open' (= reflecting) boundaries following Sklyanin? Why shouldn't this change 'the energy' of the chain? It will certainly change most of the energy eigenvalues; do you mean the lowest energy? And what do you mean by 'seeing how this would affect the solution of the Hamiltonian' -- numerically (easy) or analytically by Bethe ansatz (much more work)?
